# Python Socket gives OSError: Too many open files. Even when I close the socket

Tags: python, sockets

Here is the code,

```
def get_local_ip():    
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    except Exception as err:
        ip = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return ip
```

I recieve the OSError: Too many files error, If I call this function in a wsgi server. I am not too sure why this is happening since I am closing the Socket.

Comment: Do you open files, pipes or other sockets somewhere else in your program? Do you remember to close them when you're done with them?

Comment: No, I am not dynamically opening files, pipes or sockets anywhere in the program. I also thought that might be an issue. But looks like this is something else.